# is it possible to automate hybrid app(ios and android) by using protractor without using appium

Tags: android, ios, selenium-webdriver, protractor, appium

Can any one clear this up for me, is **protractor a tool or a framework**?

As per my understanding protractor is a framework on which selenium on built on top of.

If I want to make a mobile app (**hybrid and native**) automating using protractor what are the possibilities? please make recommendations to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It wouldn't work. Protractor is an automation tool specially designed for angular webpages. You will have to use appium for mobile apps automation. [Please check how to ask in SO](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Girish.I understood.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Appium: http://appium.io/

That is a go-to tool + framework for testing hybrid and native mobile apps.
And it is also built on top of selenium.

Comment: Sure, I looked into appium and able to do automation on hybrid apps

Answer (score 0):

Basically protractor designed for angular web pages. It mostly used for developer unit testing purposes. But if you need a mobile automation tool use appium. It built on selenium. you can find most of the features which selenium supports. Appium supports Native , Hybrid and mobile web as well.

Comment: Thank you Pramod.I understood the concept.